# CSS3 animation-timing-function property is not getting applied

Tags: html, jsfiddle, css-animations

I have a simple animation task. I have applied keyframes to define animation and provided the reference for this keyframe to elements where I need them to be applied using selectors.

Animation is working but it is **not taking the timing function that I have provided**.
Instead it takes the default "ease".

```
div {
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    width:100px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    /*-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.25, 1);*/
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}
.div1, .div2 {
    -webkit-animation:AA_Anim 1.5s;
    position:relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AA_Anim {
    from {
        left:300px;
    }
    to {
        left:0px;
    }
}
```

Sample - [JSFddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mahesh_Sasidharan/FDRRu/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it's `-webkit-animation-timing-function:`, not `-webkit-transition-timing-function` because you're working with animations

Secondly, the timing function is being overwritten because of the `-webkit-animation:AA_Anim 1.5s;`. Using the shorthand version (just `animation`) uses the given values and assumes the defaults for the rest. As a result, you must either put the timing function in each `-webkit-animation` instead or use `animation-name` and `animation-duration` instead. The second way would look as follows:

```
div {
    ...
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.25, 1);
}
.div1 > div, .div2 > div {
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name:AA_Anim;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2.5s;
}
.div1, .div2 {
    -webkit-animation-name:AA_Anim;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;
    position:relative;
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDRRu/4/)